# Looping the the data from an Api

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have an api from which I want to display the data, I have 2 arrays each one has a category how would I iterate and display these 2 categories, so category Arts and category Entertainment. I have tried something but it is not working it is giving me this error`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Books from './Books'
const url="https://json-api-smaiil.herokuapp.com/books"


const Home = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [books, setBooks] = useState({})

    const fetchData =async()=>{
    setLoading(true)
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    setBooks(books)
    }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  })
  

    return (
        <div>
          <h1 className='categories'>Categories</h1>
          {books[0].map((book)=>{
            return (<li key={book.id}>{book.category}</li>)
          })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home

{
     "Arts":[{
    "category": "Arts"
    Language: "English"
    Narrated by: "Faith G. Harper PhD LPC-S ACS ACN"
    Regular price: "$17.47"
    Release date: "03-20-18"
    bookName: "Unf--k Your Brain"
    by: "Faith G. Harper PhD LPC-S ACS ACN"
    category: "Arts and Entertainment"
    id: "1"
},
{

    Language: "English"
    Length: "1 hr and 33 mins"
    Narreted by: "James Taylor"
    Regular price: "$9.95"
    Release date: "01-31-20"
    Series: "Words + Music"
    bookName: " Break Shot: My First 21 Years"
    by: "James Taylor"
    id: "2"
}],

    "Entertainment":[{   
    "category" :"Entertainment"
    "id": "9",
    "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51tpSb0iy+L._SL500_.jpg",
    "bookName": "The Hiding Place",
    "by": "Corrie ten Boom, John Sherrill, Elizabeth Sherrill",
    "Narreted by": "Wanda McCaddon",
    "Length": "8 hrs and 14 mins",
    "Release date": "10-03-11",
    "Language": "English",
    "rating": "6,641 ratings",
    "Regular price": "$24.95",
  
},

{
    Language: "English"
    Length: "1 hr and 7 mins"
    Narreted by: "Aidan Gillen"
    Regular price: "$9.95"
    Release date: "03-31-15"
    bookName: "The Art of War"
    by: "Sun Tzu"
    id: "12"   
    rating: "19,765 ratings"
 
}]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this. cause you have to map object, not array.

```
books[0].map((book)=>{
     return (<li key={book.id}>{book.category}</li>)
})
```

to

```
Object.keys(books).map(function(key, index) {
  let book = books[key];
  return <li key={key}>{book[0].category}</li>
});
```

Comment: A question is it going to be hard to create an onClick function, so when I press on that category, to displays the books of that category, in this case (2 objects I think)per category

Answer (score 1):

try the below code:

```
      books.Arts.map((book)=>{
        return (<li key={book.id}>{book.category}</li>)
      })
```

One issue I see is the entry at index 1 of your array doesn't have key value corresponding to category which would give you undesired results.

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

`const [books, setBooks] = useState({})`

At this line you are setting the default value as an **Object** you are getting that error because the map function does not work with an object.  Change the default to an **empty array**.

`const [books, setBooks] = useState([])`

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: @Jakir Hossen answer is better.  This only is addressing why `.map()` was giving you the error, your data response is an object so his change is more appropriate